# Correct way to find the width of a scrollbar

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I have a QTableWidget that is being stretched horizontally by its layout. I looked around for a way to make the table size fit exactly its content width, all I could find is that I should manually set the width of the table to the sum of the widths of all columns plus the width of the scrollbar.

To get the width of the scrollbar I tried using `table.verticalScrollBar().width()` but it returns a value bigger than expected. However if I use `table.verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width()` the table size fits perfectly. This works for this particular application but there isn't a chance of it not working in other cases? Is there a better, more reliable way of getting this width?

Comment: Are you doing this to set the column widths, or the actual table width?  Are you using QLayouts?

Comment: To set the table width. Yes, the table is inside a layout.